# New to Ubuntu. What do I do for my display to work properly?

Tags: display, display-resolution

I'm a bit lost without Device Manager :) I decided to install Ubuntu 20 on my workshop computer as it only needs a lightweight operating system. My primary display is working and at full resolution but the second display is showing as unrecognised 17~" display and it not at optimal resolution.

I googled `Ubuntu E172FPt` but no solution.

`sudo lshw -C display; lsb_release -a; uname -a` gives me the following:

```
philip@garage:~$ sudo lshw -C display; lsb_release -a; uname -a
[sudo] password for philip: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: RV620 LE [Radeon HD 3450]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:34 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f7e20000-f7e2ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:c0000-dffff
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
Linux garage 5.4.0-31-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 7 20:20:34 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
philip@garage:~$ ^C
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no proprietary drivers for Radeon GPUs, you may try to add 
`amdgpu.dc=0` to the kernel command line at boot, to see if it works.

In case of success you could add this command to grub, by editing the `/etc/default/grub` file. Add it behind the "quiet splash" entry...